# Ryu Controller + Mininet

Tags: mininet, sdn, ryu

I am having some issues running ryu applications, I don't know if it's related to python libraries or something else?

Can someone please tell all the steps to follow for installation of ryu in ubuntu virtualbox including the python libraries?

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Maybe your question is out of the scope of SO. Here, you have to submit code you have written, with which you encounter a technical issue.

Comment: Please submit the code or where you are specifically having trouble during installation.

Answer (score 0):

These two links may be helpful.
[1]: https://www.obriain.com/training/sdn/RYU_Soft_Testbed_v2.0.pdf
[2]: https://www.obriain.com/training/sdn/RYU_Soft_Testbed_v1.6_odt.pdf

But I recommend using these links that are better and more accurate:
[3]: https://ryu.readthedocs.io
[4]: https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/Ryubook.pdf
[5]: http://mininet.org/walkthrough/
[6]: https://learning.knetsolutions.in/docs/ryu/
If you follow all the steps mentioned in the above references, the installation of ryu will be successful.
These authorities have said what python libraries need to be installed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).